# Многопоточность | Переменные | Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, android-threads

Делаю парсер, который наследуется от Runnable.

```
public class MainParse implements Runnable
```

Вызоваю его вот так:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MainParse(main_document, url, books, source, type));
t.start();
Log.e("HTML Parse", String.valueOf(getBooks().size()));
```

В конструкторе класса написал переназначение данный на те же переменные, потому что они не передаются в новый класс. Все работает. Но теперь появилась проблема:
В методе run я обрабатываю данные и сохраняю все в List. Как мне этот лист вывести в основной поток(main)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Примечание**:
Все переменные класса.

```
private volatile Document main_document;
private volatile String url = "";
private volatile List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
private volatile sources source;
private volatile types type;
```

Синхронизированная функция, которая не работает, как должна.

```
public synchronized List<Book> getBooks() {
         return books;
    }
```

Весь код класса:

```
public class MainParse implements Runnable {

private volatile Document main_document;
private volatile String url = "";
private volatile List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
private volatile sources source;
private volatile types type;

public MainParse() { }

public MainParse(Document main_document, String url, List<Book> books, sources source, types type) {
    this.main_document = main_document;
    this.url = url;
    this.books = books;
    this.source = source;
    this.type = type;
}

public void init() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new MainParse(main_document, url, books, source, type));
    t.start();
    Log.e("HTML Parse", String.valueOf(getBooks().size())); //<--- уже пустой массив
}

public synchronized List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        main_document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        switch (source) {
            case RANOBE:
                //
                break;
            case RULATE:
                switch (type) {
                    case daily_top:
                        break;
                    case recommended:
                        Elements li = main_document.select("ul.search-results li");
                        Book book_instance = new Book();

                        for(Element element : li){
                            Elements images = element.select("div.th img");
                            String img = images.first().attr("src");

                            Elements titles = element.select("p.book-tooltip a");
                            String title = titles.first().text();

                            book_instance.setImage(img);
                            book_instance.setTranslate_title(title);

                            getBooks().add(book_instance);
                        }

                        Log.i("HTML Parse", String.valueOf(getBooks().size()));//<--- массив заполнен
                        break;
                    case publisher_selected:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case WEBNOVEL:
                //
                break;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HTML Parse", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
    }
}

public void setSource(sources source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public void setURL(String value) {
    url = value;
}

public void setType(types type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, выложите код текстом

Comment: @mymedia, Добавил.

Answer (score -1):

Ещё бы чуть-чуть и я вскрылся, но нашел ответ.

Надо было добавить ссылку на класс в парсер и оттуда брать List.

```
    private Document main_document;
    private String url = "";
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    private sources source;
    private types type;

    public MainParse() {
    }

    private MainParse(Document main_document, String url, List<Book> books, sources source, types type) {
        this.main_document = main_document;
        this.url = url;
        this.books = books;
        this.source = source;
        this.type = type;

    }

    public void init() {
        Thread parser = new Thread(new Parser(this));
        parser.start();
        try {
            parser.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("HTML Parser", "BOOKs : " + String.valueOf(books.size()));
    }

    class Parser implements Runnable {

        MainParse main;

        public Parser(MainParse main) {
            this.main = main;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                main.books.add(book_instance);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("HTML Parse", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это **как-то** работает только потому, что у тебя только один параллельный поток к основному и они работают с коллекцией `main.books` последовательно и есть неявная синхронизация памяти при вызове `parser.join`. А по хорошему, твой код - это антипаттерн к многопоточному программированию.

Comment: Так что перепиши ответ или удали

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, я новичок, поэтому сделал как мог. Мне никто не ответил, поэтому пришлось искать ответ самому, хоть и не самый правильный.

Comment: Если код д..б. многопоточным, то обязательно должна присутствовать синхронизация в том или ином виде. Про многопоточность и синхронизацию много в интернете написано, и корректного кода можно добиться многими способами. **В твоём ответе** достаточно заменить объявление `books` на `List<Book> books =  java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`. Но если сценарии использования будут меняться, код будет усложняться и пр., то этого может стать недостаточно.

Comment: Вообще, твой пример использует поток, но непонятно зачем. Ты сразу в той же точке ждёшь его завершения. В таком случае параллельный поток вообще не имеет смысла, потому что ты блокируешь основной. Тебе стоит описать в вопросе исходную задачу.